# SlickGrid - Multiple versions on the same app

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I use the [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/_pages) plugin in my app. If you haven't heard of it, it is **THE** go to plugin for data grid management on the client side. I've been using it for close to a year now and have implemented it in a huge number of pages inside my app. I now want to update to the latest version, which has even cooler features but which may potentially break my app. So I was wondering if there was a way to use multiple versions of the plugin on the same app for a systematic replacement of the older version, one by one, without breaking it.

I should clarify, its a single page app. So merely adding the new version and start using, won't work - will it? Does it have a no conflict mode of sorts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but you should be able to achieve this by just changing the SlickGrid source files to use a different namespace.

Include the various SlickGrid source files twice, renaming the old files where necessary to avoid conflicts. In each of the old files, change the namespace declaration e.g.

Change

```
$.extend(true, window, {
    Slick: {
        Grid: SlickGrid
    }
});
```

to

```
$.extend(true, window, {
    Slick1: {
        Grid: SlickGrid
    }
});
```

Your grid instantiation then becomes:

```
grid = new Slick1.Grid(...
```